# React enzyme test could not find react-redux context value

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-hooks, enzyme

I am new to testing and was trying to test a form that has redux implemented, but I am getting this error:

> "could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component
> is wrapped in a "

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import { shallow,mount } from 'enzyme'

it('should check form', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<LoginForm />);
    let numberInput = wrapper.find('PhoneInput');
    numberInput.simulate('change',{
        target: {value:'jack'},
    })
    numberInput = wrapper.find('PhoneInput');
    expect(numberInput.props().value).toEqual('Jack');
});
```

I tried replacing mount with shallow too but same result. I have looked into some other similar error but couldnt figure out the exact solution

Comment: Please provide the code of the `LoginForm` component.

Comment: @slideshowp2 its a very long file, about more than 100 of lines. Let me know how can i send

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: okay I will get back to it and post it here soon